# How do I get every supported CPU flags as QEMU CPU flags?

Tags: qemu, kvm, cpuid

In my **QEMU virtual machine**, I need to use a **specific CPU model**, but with the **maximum CPU flags enabled (for performance)**.

To do that I wanted to use `/proc/cpuinfo` and use `grep` and `cut` to get the flags, but the problem is that QEMU uses different names (for example `sse4_2` is going to be `sse4.2`).

So **how would I go** about getting the CPU flags, then translating them into valid QEMU CPU flags?

Comment: Is a solution that modifies qemu code good for you?

Comment: Yeah, as long as it works

Comment: Are you working on a x86 host and running x86 guest?

Comment: Yes, to be exact an Arch Linux host and macOS Guest

Answer (score 3):

To list all the flags:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu help
```

And to test whether something works (hit ctrl+c to end it):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu base,+vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl -vga none -monitor stdio -vnc :999
```

The ["check" arg](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/CPUModels) is supposed to say some output if it's not supported (but seems not to change anything for me) eg.

```
-cpu Nehalem,check
```

And then you can get some errors in output...

And I don't know if this makes any sense...but here's an attempt to add every flag to base:

```
allflags=$(qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu help | awk '/flags/ {y=1; getline}; y {print}' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -Ev "^$" | sed -r 's|^|+|' | tr '\n' ',' | sed -r "s|,$||")

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu "base,check,${allflags}" -vga none -monitor stdio -vnc :999
```

And the output on my ryzen 1700X:

```
QEMU 6.0.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.pn [bit 18]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ds [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.acpi [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ss [bit 27]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ht [bit 28]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.tm [bit 29]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.ia64 [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:EDX.pbe [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.dtes64 [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.monitor [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ds-cpl [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.smx [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.est [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.tm2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.cid [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xtpr [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.pdcm [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.pcid [bit 17]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.dca [bit 18]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.hle [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.erms [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.invpcid [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.rtm [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.mpx [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512f [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512dq [bit 17]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512ifma [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.pcommit [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.clwb [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.intel-pt [bit 25]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512pf [bit 26]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512er [bit 27]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512cd [bit 28]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512bw [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.avx512vl [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.avx512vbmi [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.umip [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.pku [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.waitpkg [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.avx512vbmi2 [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.gfni [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.vaes [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.vpclmulqdq [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.avx512vnni [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.avx512bitalg [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.avx512-vpopcntdq [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.la57 [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.rdpid [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.bus-lock-detect [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.cldemote [bit 25]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.movdiri [bit 27]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.movdir64b [bit 28]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:ECX.pks [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.avx512-4vnniw [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.avx512-4fmaps [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.fsrm [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.avx512-vp2intersect [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.md-clear [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.serialize [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.tsx-ldtrk [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.avx512-fp16 [bit 23]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.spec-ctrl [bit 26]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.stibp [bit 27]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.core-capability [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EDX.ssbd [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EAX.avx512-bf16 [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:EDX.3dnowext [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:EDX.3dnow [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.extapic [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.ibs [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.xop [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.skinit [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.wdt [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.lwp [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.fma4 [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.tce [bit 17]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.nodeid-msr [bit 19]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.tbm [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.perfctr-nb [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.wbnoinvd [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.ibpb [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.ibrs [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.amd-stibp [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.amd-ssbd [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000008H:EBX.amd-no-ssb [bit 26]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.xstore [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.xstore-en [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.xcrypt [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.xcrypt-en [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.ace2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.ace2-en [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.phe [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.phe-en [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.pmm [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.C0000001H:EDX.pmm-en [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.40000001H:EAX.kvm-mmu [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.40000001H:EAX.kvm-msi-ext-dest-id [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.lbrv [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svm-lock [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.tsc-scale [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.vmcb-clean [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.flushbyasid [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.decodeassists [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.pause-filter [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.pfthreshold [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.avic [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.v-vmsave-vmload [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.vgif [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.8000000AH:EDX.svme-addr-chk [bit 28]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(10AH).ibrs-all [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(10AH).rsba [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(10AH).ssb-no [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(10AH).tsx-ctrl [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(10AH).taa-no [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(CFH).split-lock-detect [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(345H).full-width-write [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-vintr-pending [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-tsc-offset [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-hlt-exit [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-invlpg-exit [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-mwait-exit [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-rdpmc-exit [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-rdtsc-exit [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-cr3-load-noexit [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-cr3-store-noexit [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-cr8-load-exit [bit 19]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-cr8-store-exit [bit 20]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-flexpriority [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-vnmi-pending [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-movdr-exit [bit 23]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-io-exit [bit 24]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-io-bitmap [bit 25]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-mtf [bit 27]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-msr-bitmap [bit 28]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-monitor-exit [bit 29]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-pause-exit [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48EH).vmx-secondary-ctls [bit 31]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-apicv-xapic [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-ept [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-desc-exit [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-rdtscp-exit [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-apicv-x2apic [bit 4]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-vpid [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-wbinvd-exit [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-unrestricted-guest [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-apicv-register [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-apicv-vid [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-ple [bit 10]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-rdrand-exit [bit 11]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-invpcid-exit [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-vmfunc [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-shadow-vmcs [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-encls-exit [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-rdseed-exit [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-pml [bit 17]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48BH).vmx-xsaves [bit 20]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48DH).vmx-intr-exit [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48DH).vmx-nmi-exit [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48DH).vmx-vnmi [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48DH).vmx-preemption-timer [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48DH).vmx-posted-intr [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-nosave-debugctl [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-ack-intr [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-save-pat [bit 18]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-pat [bit 19]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-save-efer [bit 20]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-efer [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-save-preemption-timer [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-clear-bndcfgs [bit 23]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-clear-rtit-ctl [bit 25]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48FH).vmx-exit-load-pkrs [bit 29]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-noload-debugctl [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-ia32e-mode [bit 9]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-perf-global-ctrl [bit 13]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-pat [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-efer [bit 15]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-bndcfgs [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-rtit-ctl [bit 18]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(490H).vmx-entry-load-pkrs [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-store-lma [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-activity-hlt [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-activity-shutdown [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-activity-wait-sipi [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-vmwrite-vmexit-fields [bit 29]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(485H).vmx-zero-len-inject [bit 30]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-ept-execonly [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-page-walk-4 [bit 6]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-page-walk-5 [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH) [bit 14]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-ept-2mb [bit 16]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-ept-1gb [bit 17]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invept [bit 20]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-eptad [bit 21]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-ept-advanced-exitinfo [bit 22]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invept-single-context [bit 25]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invept-all-context [bit 26]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invvpid [bit 32]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invvpid-single-addr [bit 40]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invept-single-context [bit 41]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invvpid-all-context [bit 42]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(48CH).vmx-invept-single-context-noglobals [bit 43]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(480H).vmx-ins-outs [bit 54]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(480H).vmx-true-ctls [bit 55]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: MSR(491H).vmx-eptp-switching [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.14H:ECX.intel-pt-lip [bit 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running qemu with `-cpu` option with an old cpu model, for example `Nehalem`. All code examples are form qemu 5.0 sources. I assume you are familiar with the `cpuid` instruction.
In `target\i386\cpu.c` file you can find

```
static X86CPUDefinition builtin_x86_defs[] = {
```

array with the available cpu models. There is an entry for Nehalem:

```
.name = "Nehalem",
        .features[FEAT_1_EDX] =
            CPUID_VME | CPUID_SSE2 | CPUID_SSE | CPUID_FXSR | CPUID_MMX |
```

For example, `FEAT_1_EDX` describes the values returned for cpuid 1 execution in edx register for this cpu model. You can see also all other emulated codes.

When running qemu with kvm acceleration, it will send this data to kvm in `target\i386\kvm.c` in `kvm_arch_init_vcpu` function.
This function initializes `cpuid_data` and calls `kvm_vcpu_ioctl(cs, KVM_SET_CPUID2, &cpuid_data);`.

The idea is to execute cpuid instruction for the codes you want to adjust and add the available bits to according `cpuid_data` entries just before sending them to kvm.

For example adjusting of cpuid 1 edx and ecx can be done so:

```
struct kvm_cpuid_entry2 *c = cpuid_find_entry(&cpuid_data.cpuid, 1, 0);
if (c) {
  c->ecx |= cpuid1_ecx;
  c->edx |= cpuid1_edx;
}
```

where `cpuid1_ecx` and `cpuid1_edx` are values returned in ecx and edx on cpuid 1 execution on your host.
Since the feature bits are returned in different cpuid functions, you have to manually choose which to adjust. A good starting point would be to adjust all the FEAT_xx entries found in `builtin_x86_defs` for your cpu.

Newer cpus can have more features entries, modelling these is difficult, but possible.

Comment: The thing is I want this to be dynamic, like the flags change for the CPU

Comment: You mean changing cpu flags during guest execution?

Comment: Yes, and be able to support any CPU (like not hardcoding custom flags)

Comment: Changing processor features during guest execution is dangerous, since the guest does not expect such behaviour. 
Guest OS can check cpuid at it's startup, configure itself accordingly and dont check the features anymore.
But if you still want it then you can place your changes in `accel\kvm\kvm-all.c` in `int kvm_cpu_exec(CPUState *cpu)` in the cycle right before
`run_ret = kvm_vcpu_ioctl(cpu, KVM_RUN, 0);` call. You have to call kvm_vcpu_ioctl KVM_SET_CPUID2 with the new features.
There is no hardcoding of flags in my solution. All mentioned flags are already in qemu sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to list the avaliable CPU models;

```
./qemu-system-<target> -cpu ?
```

target option can be arm, aarch64, avr, i386 etc.